# Fire a trigger when Account is enabled as customer

Tags: apex, trigger, community, customer-portal

I am trying to set up a trigger to fire when an Account is enabled as a Customer but without success. The after update trigger is not firing at all even after the field "isCustomerPortal" is updated to "true". I also noticed that the LastModifiedDate is not updated after enabling the Account as a Customer.

What is the correct way to set such a trigger ?

Thank you for your help.

Edit :
There is no triggers fired for Contacts as well.

Comment: Does a user record gets created?

Comment: Yes, that's a Lead I have in mind if there is no trigger fired for Account

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several actions that don't fire triggers or any of the other normal processes. [Operations That Don't Invoke Triggers](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_ignoring_operations.htm) goes in to a list of things that don't fire triggers, but there are a few others that are apparently missing from the list. For whatever reason, these actions are not "normal" actions in the context of Salesforce and don't follow the normal rules. As I stated in [a previous answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/101121/2984), things like activating or deactivating products also exhibit this behavior. These "shadow updates" were apparently written to ensure that these actions couldn't fail.

Comment: I had thought that since the portal user activation operation is not on that list, it means that it is firing triggers and I might be doing something wrong. But apparently it is not possible because I'm not finding answers to my queries anywhere.
I'll take your answer as best answer for now although there is no official statement that the triggers are not fired when activating a portal User.

Comment: @THEDJA I found that out experimentally years ago, but I've never seen it in the docs, either. There really should be a bug logged for it.

Comment: I might open a case support for it to update the question just for a future reference, because they are usually slow to answer such questions and I don't have the luxury of time to find a solution for my usecase.
Thank you for your answer.